# Less verbose way to flatten & join two arrays in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do the following.

I have two 2D arrays, X and Y. Each is 100x100 elements. I want to linearize/flatten them into 10,000x1 columns and then concatenate them so I am left with a single matrix that is 10,000x2. In MATLAB I could do the following

```
BigMatrix = [X(:) Y(:)]
```

I want do the same thing in Python. After playing around with it for a bit I've been able to replicate the MATLAB result, albeit in quite a verbose manner, shown below. Is there a better, more succinct way to accomplish this?

```
BigMatrix = np.concatenate(
    (X.reshape((10000,1), order = 'F'), 
     Y.reshape((10000,1), order = 'F')),
      axis=1)
```

Comment: The MATLAB syntax will be shorter however you do it because everything is designed around matrices. Just about the only thing you can do is `X.flatten()` or `X.reshape(-1)` to flatten an array.

Comment: That's an acurate translation, assuming the `F` order matters and you want (n,2) shape.

Comment: Yes, if I don't include `F` I get what I want except reversed (1st column is 2nd and 2nd column is 1st).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want, and what you have is perfectly valid. However here are some other methods that you might find more "succinct."

### Using [`np.ndarray.flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

> Return a copy of the array collapsed into one dimension.

You can also specify whether to treat it as column major or row major.

In order to get the result you want (a m x 2 matrix, with each flattened matrix as a column) you can then use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

```
BigMatrix = np.column_stack([X.flatten(order = 'F'), Y.flatten(order = 'F')])
```

Or if you are looking for *really* succinct, as @ssp mentioned, you can use [numpy indexing routines](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.indexing.html) (which basically give special behavior to slices). There are two for concatenation, one for each axis. `r_` is for row-wise (the first axis) and `c_` is for column-wise (the second axis) so to get your m x 2 matrix you can do:

```
BigMatrix = np.c_[X.flatten(order = 'F'), Y.flatten(order = 'F')]
```

### Performance?

As far as performance goes, you might be better off with your original code, as @hpaulj suggests. Here is a simple timing of the three methods, where each method is done 1 million times for your size of 100x100 matrices.

```py
from timeit import timeit

print("c_ w/ flatten", timeit(
    setup="import numpy as np\nX=np.random.standard_normal((100,100))\nY=np.random.standard_normal((100,100))",
    stmt="Z=np.c_[X.flatten(order='F'), Y.flatten(order='F')]"
))

print("column_stack w/ flatten", timeit(
    setup="import numpy as np\nX=np.random.standard_normal((100,100))\nY=np.random.standard_normal((100,100))",
    stmt="Z=np.column_stack((X.flatten(order='F'), Y.flatten(order='F')))"
))

print("concatenate w/ reshape", timeit(
    setup="import numpy as np\nX=np.random.standard_normal((100,100))\nY=np.random.standard_normal((100,100))",
    stmt="Z=np.concatenate((X.reshape((10000,1),order='F'), Y.reshape((10000,1),order='F')), axis=1)"
))
```

and we get

```
c_ w/ flatten            44.47710300699691
column_stack w/ flatten  29.201319813000737
concatenate w/ reshape   27.67507728200144
```

Surprisingly, the column_stack and flatten is comparable, while the index routine is significantly slower.

(If there is anything I missed with this performance analysis, let me know. I am not a performance guru).

Comment: `np.c_[X.flatten(order='F'), Y.flatten(order='F')]` should work too.

Comment: Hm, that is giving me a 20000x1 matrix. I wanted 10000x2

Comment: @Nukesub I have just updated the answer to reflect your original intent. I misunderstood at first.

Comment: When I try to use the `._c` method I get the following error: `module 'numpy' has no attribute '_c'`

Comment: Oops. I misspelled. It's `c_` not `_c`. Fixed.

Comment: Got it! Works now.

Comment: I think the original concatenate is clearer, and probably faster.  `flatten` makes a copy, `reshape` a `view`.  Both `column_stack` and `c_` reshape to (n,1) before calling `concatenate`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! I didn't know that about views vs copies. I've updated the answer to include a performance comparison.

Comment: The code for `c_` and `column_stack` is free for the reading :)

Answer (score 1):

With a small 2 array:

```
In [404]: x = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
```

`reshape` with order F is the most direct equivalent of the MATLAB `(:)` indexing, producing a (n,1) array.  (Is `x(:).'` the syntax for a (1,n) matrix?)

```
In [405]: x1 = x.reshape((4,1),order='F')
In [406]: x
Out[406]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
In [407]: x1
Out[407]: 
array([[0],
       [2],
       [1],
       [3]])
```

Joining two such 'column vectors' is easy:

```
In [408]: np.concatenate((x1,x1), axis=1)
Out[408]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [3, 3]])
```

`np.stack` is a version of `concatenate` that creates a new dimension and joins on that.  With `axis=0` it's the same as `np.array((x,x))`

```
In [409]: np.stack((x,x), axis=2)
Out[409]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [3, 3]]])
```

A order F reshape creates the 2 column array as before:

```
In [411]: np.stack((x,x), axis=2).reshape((-1,2),order='F')
Out[411]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [3, 3]])
```

or using the default order:

```
In [412]: np.stack((x,x), axis=2).reshape((-1,2))
Out[412]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

`numpy` is a Python package, using functions, indexing and methods.  It doesn't alter or add to the basic Python syntax.